# Stitch two independent branch histories together

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have two independent branches in my Git repository:

```
A---B---C branch "old"
X---Y---Z branch "master"
```

I want to generate the following history:

```
A---B---C---X---Y---Z
```

I tried this with the following rebase command (current branch is "master"):

```
git rebase --strategy=recursive --strategy-option=theirs old master
```

This fails with:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: Could not parse object 'fb56e6e20ea4a605503732df1f5a0a407808dffa^'
```

`fb56e6` is the first commit of the "old" branch.

As an alternative I used the cherry pick command (current branch is "master"):

```
git rev-list --reverse old | git cherry-pick --stdin --keep-redundant-commits -X theirs
```

This works fine, but all commits get a new "committer". Is there a way to tell cherry pick that it should not set the committer? If not, is there a way to achieve what I want with rebase?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent"? Do they meet anywhere in the history?

Comment: No, they don't meet (I think that is the problem that git rebase stumbles over)

Comment: Maybe [git-reparent](https://github.com/MarkLodato/git-reparent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using `git filter-branch`:

```
FIX_COMMITTER='
    if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" != "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"; then
        GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
    fi
'
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "$FIX_COMMITTER" -- master
```

Source of the idea: https://gist.github.com/maciej/5875814

Answer (score 1):

I like your cherry-pick approach.  Just run the standard "set my author info" commands before doing cherry-pick to match the "commiter" data you want to preserve.

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

And then set the author info back to yourself when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rebase an unrelated history on top of another one:

```
git switch master
git rebase --root --onto old
```

Notice the error message:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: Could not parse object 'fb56e6e20ea4a605503732df1f5a0a407808dffa^'
```

`fb56e6e...^` means that it tried to get the first parent of `fb56e6e`,
but that commit doesn’t exist since `fb56e6e` is a root commit.

#### Preserving committer

This one is more fun.

```
git switch master
git rebase --root --onto old --exec 'git -c committer.name="$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%cn)" -c committer.email="$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%ce)" commit --amend --no-edit'
```

#### But what about preserving the committer date?

Left as an exercise for the reader.